# How to include graphics with width in the exam class?

Tags: graphics, exam

I am trying to compose an exam with a figure as part of the question. However, I am having trouble using the standard `\includegraphics` command with `pdflatex`. I can not specify the arguments to `\includegraphics` in the square brackets. If I remove the square bracket (optional arguments), then it compiles without issue. I've tried wrapping it in the `\fullwidth{}` command to no avail.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[] True/False questions.
\begin{parts}
\part[2] True or False.\vspace*{1in}
An image:
\begin{figure}    
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{file-which-exists}  
\end{figure}
\end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}`
```

Comment: A general comment: Using `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth` might be more appropriate. The reason for this is that `\textwidth` may be fixed across your entire document, while `\linewidth` may vary, depending on the environment you're in. For example, in `enumerate` or `itemize` (typical for question-style documents like an examination), the `\linewidth` is smaller than `\textwidth` (due to the added indent). This leads to a better horizontal fit on the page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are loading the wrong package: it's not **graphics**, but **graphicx**

There's no need to use a `figure` environment: `center` or `flushleft` will do as well (but none of them is really necessary). Just think to the graphic object as a big character.